# WordPress Dynamic Tinymce listbox

Tags: javascript, wordpress, listbox

what i am trying to do is dynamically generate WordPress tinymcs listbox values. but it seems my getValue function is not working well or its not possible to add getvalue() function to value parameter. this code is not working. please tell me how to do this. i need this for my new plugin development. sorry for bad english :(

here i have posted the code bellow

```
(function() {
        tinymce.PluginManager.add('AP_tc_button', function( editor, url ) {
            editor.addButton( 'AP_tc_button', {
                text: 'My test button',
                icon: 'wp_code',
                onclick: function() {
        editor.windowManager.open( {
            title: 'Select Your AD',
            body: [
            {
                type: 'listbox', 
                name: 'level', 
                label: 'Header level', 
               values: getValues()
            }],
            onsubmit: function( e ) {
                editor.insertContent('dd');
            }
        });
    }
            });
        });


    })();


    function getValues() {
         //Set new values to myKeyValueList 
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.settings.myKeyValueList = [{text: 'newtext', value: 'newvalue'}];
          return editor.settings.myKeyValueList;
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `return` statement to

```
return tinyMCE.activeEditor.settings.myKeyValueList;
```

variable `editor` is probably undefined in global scope.